# 'object 'rlang_hash' not found' when using MODISTools functions in R

Tags: r, r-modis

I am trying to follow the steps on [the documentation](https://docs.ropensci.org/MODISTools/articles/modistools-vignette.html) and use the `MODISTools` R package to download Land Cover data.

I installed `MODISTools` and imported the library into my R session

```
install.packages("MODISTools")
library(MODISTools)
```

Then when I try to run any `mt_*()` function, I get the following error.

```
mt_products()
```

> Error in encl$`_hash`(c(encl$`_f_hash`, args, lapply(encl$`_additional`, : object 'rlang_hash' not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating the version of `rlang` package to `0.4.10` worked

Answer (score 2):

Tried the OP's code and it is working in `R 4.0.4` and `rlang version 0.4.10`

```
library(MODISTools)
products <- mt_products()
str(products)
'data.frame':   34 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ product          : chr  "Daymet" "ECO4ESIPTJPL" "ECO4WUE" "MCD12Q1" ...
 $ description      : chr  "Daily Surface Weather Data (Daymet) on a 1-km Grid for North America, Version 4" "ECOSTRESS Evaporative Stress Index PT-JPL (ESI) Daily L4 Global 70 m" "ECOSTRESS Water Use Efficiency (WUE) Daily L4 Global 70 m" "MODIS/Terra+Aqua Land Cover Type (LC) Yearly L3 Global 500 m SIN Grid" ...
 $ frequency        : chr  "1 day" "Varies" "Varies" "1 year" ...
 $ resolution_meters: int  1000 70 70 500 500 500 500 1000 500 500 ...
```

Comment: products <- mt_products() still gives me the same error. Any idea how to fix? I tried reinstalling rlang as well

Comment: @zstar I used `packageVersion('rlang')#
[1] ‘0.4.10’` on `R 4.0.4`

Comment: Sweet! I had `rlang` version `'0.4.7'` installed, and somehow `update.packages()` didn;t update it. So removed and re-installed version `0.4.10` and works fine now