# R cannot connect to SQLite

Tags: r, database, sqlite, connection, database-connection

My question is same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67326739/error-in-evaluating-the-argument-drv-in-selecting-a-method-for-function-dbcon), but still cannot be solved. My code is:

```
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "myDB.db")
```

No matter `myDB.db` exists or not, I got the same error message. The error message I got:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'drv' in selecting a method for function 'dbConnect': .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RSQLite', details:
  call: NULL
  error: 'hash' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rlang'
```

Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: I would pay attention to the second error: `error: 'hash' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rlang'` Maybe restart the R session and update it.

Comment: @Bloxx Thanks for your reply. If I run `sessionInfo()` I can see that I have `rlang_0.4.9`. If I run `rlang::hash` I have `Error: 'hash' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rlang'
`. I tried to restart RStudio and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: you should still update rlang. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66308294/object-rlang-hash-not-found-when-using-modistools-functions-in-r

Comment: yes, as @dww wrote, update your rlang. The latest version is `rlang_0.4.12`. If you will have problems updating rlang, check your version of R (not Rstudio). Updating R to the latest version will help updating rlang. Sorry, if I complicated too much :)

Comment: @Bloxx I updated both R and RStudio and now it works! Thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear that. :)